# Getting error while scheduling apex class : "You must select an apex class that has a parameterless constructor"

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, error-messages, scheduled-job

I have an apex class that was scheduled and working fine. Due to inactive user the scheduled job has stopped working and now I am trying to create a new schedule for the apex class but getting below error.

**"You must select an apex class that has a parameterless constructor"**

As per my understanding we dont need to create a parameterless constructor specifically. Also as it was working before it should work now as well.

Tried compiling all classes but no luck.

Need you expertise to solve this issue. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apex classes have a default, no-argument constructor, but as soon as you declare any other constructor you lose it.

If your apex class has any constructor, then you need to explicitly create the no-arg constructor yourself.

e.g.

```
public class MyClass{
    Integer memberInt;

    public MyClass(Integer oneArg){
        memberInt = oneArg;
    }

    // Since this class has at least one constructor defined, we lose the
    //   automatic no-arg constructor.
    // If you need a no-arg constructor, you need to write it yourself
    public MyClass(){
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.
So my concern is how this class was scheduled before and working correctly till now.